# Can we add column to an existing table in AWS Athena using SQL query?

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-athena

I have a table in AWS Athena which contains 2 records. Is there a SQL query using which a new column can be inserted in to the table?

Comment: [Check the documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/types-of-updates.html).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can find more information about adding columns to table in [Athena documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/en_us/athena/latest/ug/types-of-updates.html#updates-add-columns-end-of-table)

Or you can use CTAS

For example, you have a table with

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE sample_test(
  id string)
LOCATION
  's3://bucket/path'
```

and you can create another table from `sample_test` with the query

```
CREATE TABLE new_test
AS 
SELECT *, 'new' AS new_col FROM sample_test
```

You can use any available query after `AS`

Comment: Here the 2 records have been given value 'new' for the created column new_col . Is it possible to give different values for different records for the created column new_col? Thanks a lot.

Comment: @VarunKumar Yes, you can join your current table with another. After `AS` you can write any SQL query with `SELECT`

Comment: I have 2  records,each with a unique id.For each of those 2 records I want to give a different value for the newly created column. But I am not able to get the sql query for that.

Comment: Do you suggest Inner joining?

Comment: yes, you can do it with inner or left join. create new table with 2 columns and 2 record, where first column has old values and second column has new values, then join your table with this new table on first column, then you can drop first column

Answer (score 1):

This is mainly for future readers like me, who was struggling to get this working for Hive table with AVRO data and if you don't want to create new table i.e updating schema of the existing table. It works for csv using 'add columns', but not for Hive + AVRO. For Hive + AVRO, to append columns at the end, before partition columns, the solution is available at this [link](https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Support-Questions/Can-Hive-avro-tables-support-changing-schemas/td-p/102881). However, there are couple of things to note that, we need to pass full schema to the literal attribute and not just the changes; and (not sure why but) we had to alter hive table for all 3 things in the same order - 1. add columns using `add columns` 2. `set tblproperties` and 3. `set serdeproperties`. Hopefully it helps someone.